# JPQL: Validation fails for Query with Join

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am struggling to get a query working in JPQL.

I have following Entities (stripped down):

**Conversation**
One Conversation has many Messages.
One Conversation has many UserConversations.

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "conversations")
data class Conversation(
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: IDType = 0
) {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation")
    lateinit var messages: MutableSet<Message>

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation")
    lateinit var userConversation: MutableSet<UserConversation>
}
```

**Message**
Many Messages have one Conversation.

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
data class Message(
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: IDType = 0
) {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE], optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "conversation_id", nullable = false)
    lateinit var conversation: Conversation
}
```

**UserConversation**
Many UserConversation have one Conversation.

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_conversations")
data class UserConversation(
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),

    @Column(nullable = false)
    var allowHistory: Boolean = true,

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: IDType = 0
) {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE], optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "conversation_id", nullable = false)
    lateinit var conversation: Conversation
}
```

In order to help you understand those entities: Think of channels or group chats.
A Conversation is such a group.
A Message gets posted to the group.
A UserConversation describes the relationship between a user and such a group.

The scenario I want to implement:
If a user is **NOT** allowed to see a conversation history, only the messages after he joined should be shown.

The native solution looks something like this:

```
SELECT     messages.*, user_conversations.*
FROM       messages

INNER JOIN user_conversations
        ON messages.conversation_id = user_conversations.conversation_id

WHERE      user_conversations.id IN (42) # I might want to fetch multiple userConversations at once
AND        messages.created_at >= IF(user_conversations.allow_history, messages.created_at, user_conversations.created_at)
```

I would like to place this in a JPA repository.
Since I am fetching for Messages in the first place I was thinking to put it into my MessageRepository (This is no must).

I need to be able to link userConversations to their message later, hence I tried to introduce a custom result:

```kotlin
// query here
fun findAllByUserConversationIdIn(userConversationIds: Collection<IDType>): Collection<UserConversationMessage>

interface UserConversationMessage {
    val message: Message
    val userConversation: UserConversation
}
```

Here is the JPQL I came up with:

```
SELECT
    m as message,
    uc as userConversation
FROM
    Message m
INNER JOIN UserConversation uc
    ON uc.conversation.id = m.conversation.id
WHERE uc.id IN (?1)
AND m.createdAt >= CASE WHEN uc.allowHistory THEN m.createdAt ELSE uc.createdAt END
```

Validation fails, though.

Can you help me?

Cheers

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @Andronicus
```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Collection fin.message.datasource.MessageRepository.findAllByUserConversationIdIn(java.util.Collection)!
 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
 at
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be so easy.
My JPQL is not that bad actually.
The error lies here:

```
AND m.createdAt >= CASE WHEN uc.allowHistory THEN m.createdAt ELSE uc.createdAt END
```

It should be

```
AND m.createdAt >= CASE WHEN uc.allowHistory = 1 THEN m.createdAt ELSE uc.createdAt END
```

I was very surprised that this query actually returned what I wanted.